# Angular - Unable to set http response types properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a service which exposes some functions that uses `HttpClient` requests, one of them being a `post`:

```
post<T>(url: string, data: any, params?: {[key: string]: any}): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
  return this.http.post<T>(this.host + url, data, this.getRequestOptions(params));
}
```

The important thing here is the return signature `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`.

Then when I call the function I get two problems:

```
this.api.post<string>('/tokens', credentials).subscribe((token: string) => {});
```

The first problem is that I can't pass in a type with `<string>` due to an lint error saying:

```
Expected 0 type arguments but got 1
```

The second problem is that all data in the responses becomes the type `HttpEvent<T>`, instead of what I send in, in this example it should be of type `string`.

So in the example above I get this error:

> Argument of type '(token: string) => void' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(value: HttpEvent<{}>) => void'.   Types of
>   parameters 'token' and 'value' are incompatible.
>       Type 'HttpEvent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>         Type 'HttpProgressEvent' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How can I fix this so that I can set my response type properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 post<T>(url: string, data: any, params?: {[key: string]: any}): Observable<T> {
            return this.http.post<T>(this.host + url, data, this.getRequestOptions(params)).map((res: T) => res);
        }
```

Comment: Despite the fact I'd expect this to work, the map is pretty useless :D

Comment: It also works without the map: https://plnkr.co/edit/dvrgTCxSuEijXWqGes4f?p=preview

Comment: The return signature of `getRequestOptions` was set to `: any`, which was messing it up for some strange reason.

Comment: Agree, with new HttpClient map is unnecessary